# Issues with While Loop in Python 3 - loop breaks when it should repeat

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, input, while-loop

I am currently working on a Yahtzee game written in Python 3.5. I have defined a function that asks the user to type in the names of the people who will be playing, before checking if this is correct.

```
def get_player_names():

   while True:
      print("Who are playing today? ")

      players = [str(x) for x in input().split()]

      n = len(players)

      if n == 1:
          for p in players:
              print("So", p, "is playing alone today.")

          choice = input("Is this correct?(y/n)\n")

          if choice == "y" or "Y":
              break
          elif choice == "n" or "N":
              continue
          else:
              print("You should enter either y/Y or n/N")
              continue

      elif n > 1:
          print("So today, ", n, " people are playing, and their names are: ")

          for p in players:
              print(p)

          choice = input("Is this correct?(y/n)\n")

          if choice == "y" or "Y":
              break
          elif choice == "n" or "N":
              continue
          else:
              print("You should enter either y/Y or n/N")
              continue

      else:
          print("Sorry, but at least one person has to participate")
          continue

  placeholder()


def placeholder():
  print("KTITENS")

get_player_names()
```

The program creates the list of players without a problem, as well as when the user confirm that the names of the players are correct, at which point the loop breaks and the next function is called. (Which is currently just a function that prints KITTENS. The problem is that if the user enters "n"/"N" or something else, I would like the loop to repeat, but it breaks instead.

Hopefully someone can  assist me! Apologies if this question is a duplicate, but I couldn't find a similar question concerning Python 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem are those lines :

```
if choice == "y" or "Y":
    break
elif choice == "n" or "N":
    # Some stuff
```

Which should be :

```
if choice == "y" or choice == "Y":
    break
elif choice == "n" or choice == "N":
    # Some stuff
```

Indeed, `or "Y"` is always true, hence the `break` is always called.

You can check this by typing this in your python console :

```
>>> if 'randomstring': print('Yup, this is True')
Yup, this is True
```

Comment: This worked nicely, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
if choice == "y" or "Y":
          break
      elif choice == "n" or "N":
          continue
```

to

```
if choice == "y" or choice =="Y":
          break
      elif choice == "n" or choice =="N":
          continue
```

`'Y'` is a non empty string and therefore `bool('Y')` is always `True`

You can read here about [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Comment: This worked nicely, thank you very much. Two answer got posted with a minute's difference and had the same solution, so I checked the other answer as the solution, but still thanks!